# Keep Interop Form to Top of VB6 Application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, vb6, interop, winforms-interop

I'm using the InteropFormsToolkit version 2.1. I'm trying to make sure that when a .NET form loads from an event being thrown on the VB6 form, that the .NET form can stay on top. I've tried many things and can't get anything to work. I've tried everything from z-index, to adding a managed call into User32.dll to push it to the forefront, etc.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: ShowDialog() or TopMost should work.  To get Show(owner) to work so it stays on top you'll need to get a suitable wrapper for the VB6 window.  An IWin32Window or NativeWindow.  No idea if you can get that out of the toolkit, ought to be possible.

Comment: ShowDialog does not as events bubble down to VB6.

Answer (score 1):

In vb6 you can use as:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
OnTopMe Me, True
End Sub
```

and following code in module

```
Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "User32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long, ByVal cX As Long, ByVal cY As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long


Public Sub OnTopMe(FormID As Object, onTop As Boolean)
     If onTop = True Then SetWindowPos FormID.hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE
     If onTop = False Then SetWindowPos FormID.hwnd, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE
End Sub
```

I don't know about how to do it in .Net

Comment: So the issue I may run into is that the VB6 app opens a .NET winform using .show. Then, the .NET winform raises an event that bubbles to VB6. The reason for this is that there are several other VB6 "detail" forms that must be shown when choosing buttons, etc from the .NET form. The detail form would need to be on top. When the detail form is closed, that's where the .NET form slips behind (sometimes) the VB6 main form. HTH.

Comment: you means that Your VB6 app => Loads .Net Form => Event on .Net Form => Captured in VB6 and show the vb6 form on the top on that event. If I am wrong some where then let me explain with every event as vb6 is event driven

Comment: You are correct. So VB6 App => Contains FrmMain.vb (VB6) => Button loads frmOrder (.NET) => Button on frmOrder fires LoadDetailsEvent in VB6 FrmMain => In event, VB6 FrmOrderDetails.vb (VB6) is ShowDialog(). When FrmOrderDetails is closed, frmOrder seems to slip behind FrmMain.

Comment: I am taking some assumptions for resolving the issue are: (i) the Form which is to be displayed is unloaded state; (ii) On .net form event you are able to show vb6 form; (iii) Vb6 Form must not be a MDI Child Form, as they can't be show on top;

Create a separate module and paste the second part of above code in it and what ever the form you want to show on top on event of on_load write "OnTopMe Me, True", Me here means the form which you want to show on top and thus change change it which your form name true to show on top and false to not show on top

Comment: No. I've abandoned this project as even the suggestions weren't solving the issue.